# VMWare Converter FAILED: Unable to find the system volume

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-converter

I'm trying to convert a physical Windows XP Professional computer into a VM using `VMWare vCenter Converter Standalone 5.0.1`.

When the process completed, I had the following output:

## Conversion status:

**Type:** Convert physical machine to virtual machine 
**Status:** FAILED Unable to find the system volume, reconfiguration is not possible 
**Running time:** 1 hours and 14 minutes 
**Completed:** 96%

## Log highlights:

Error: An error occurred during reconfiguration 
Processing the reconfiguration datastore. 
Updating drive letters for the destination volume layout 
Update boot.ini on the destination machine's system volume. 
Update the boot sectors on the destination machine. 
Completed cloning volume 'C:'. 
Starting to clone volume 'C:'. 
Completed cloning volume ''. 
A snapshot of the source system was created successfully. 
Creating a snapshot of the source system. 
Task: Convert physical machine.

I mounted the resulting volume (`*.vmdk`) on another vm to look at the `boot.ini` that was pulled from the physical machine, since several threads referred to this as the source of the problem, it's contents is as follows:

```
[boot loader]
timeout=30
default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(2)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)parition(2)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" /noexecute=optin /fastdetect
```

Also, when looking at the partitions it appears that there are two, one that's NTFS and contains the Operating system and the windows directory on `Disk 0`
[image: Disk 0 is the resulting drive mounted]

I also found some threads that said that the issue might be with the `*.vmx` file that was generated, at their suggestion I tried changing the `ide:0.0present` value to `false`, and changing the parameter `ide0:0.filename` to `scsi:0.0.fileName` along with adding `scsi0:0.present="true"` and adding `scsi0.virtualDev="buslogic"`

But all this did when booting up was result in an `File: \ntldr` `Status: 0xc0000225` error from the Windows Boot Manager.

It seems to me that maybe the `boot.ini` is pointing at the wrong partition, but I don't know enough about the config file to really change anything about it.